# rkhunter sends no email

Tags: rkhunter

rkhunter sends no email

I installed rkhunter on a Ubuntu 12.04.3 server

```
sudo apt-get install rkhunter
```

it installed the 1.3.8 version of rkhunter

```
sudo apt-show-versions rkhunter
rkhunter/precise uptodate 1.3.8-10
```

rkhunter gives back some messages

```
sudo rkhunter -c --rwo
```

but I do not get any daily email

Comment: You will have to look in `/etc/default/rkhunter` and set the following `CRON_DAILY_RUN="true"` and `CRON_DB_UPDATE="true"`.

Comment: The solution was setting these two values which were lacking
> sudo vim /etc/default/rkhunter

> CRON_DAILY_RUN="true"

> CRON_DB_UPDATE="true"

will post a more detailed info later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- check cron.daily did run

> less /var/log/syslog

it did run in my case

2- run the main command contained in the cron routine

> sudo less /etc/cron.daily/rkhunter
>
> sudo /usr/bin/nice -n 0 /usr/bin/rkhunter --cronjob --report-warnings-only --appendlog > rkhunter20131127

if it does not work, add echos to /etc/cron.daily/rkhunter to display the parameters

> sudo vim /etc/cron.daily/rkhunter
>
> echo "cron_daily_run".$CRON_DAILY_RUN;

I found out the value for CRON_DAILY_RUN was empty

3- therefore

> sudo vim /etc/default/rkhunter

changed

> CRON_DAILY_RUN=""
>
> CRON_DB_UPDATE=""

to

> CRON_DAILY_RUN="true"
>
> CRON_DB_UPDATE="true"